# Записать динамическую переменную в JSON файл в .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci, allure

нужно записать в json файл динамическую переменную $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE" из gitlab, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

пробовал так:

```
after_script:
        - touch allure-results/executor.json
        - echo '{"name":"Gitlab", "buildName":"$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE", "type":"gitlab"}' > allure-results/executor.json
```

но в таком случае в файл записывается имя переменной, а не сама переменная